# Single home partition for two separate systems - one 32bit, the other 64bit

Tags: dual-boot

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 (32bit) and want to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit). I have a separate home partition. Is it possible to share the home partition with both versions of Ubuntu whilst the transition goes through ?

Comment: Applications get upgraded and older data may not be compatible. For example, my keepassX converted it file format. So my 14.04 install cannot read new 16.04 version. I prefer to use data partition over /home but some of the update issues still exist.

Comment: I agree with @oldfred. This should work, but there may be some instances that once you boot 16.04, and some apps update their config files or databases, you won't be able to use those same apps from 14.04 again. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1):

You can not share a single `/home`-partition with two different versions of Ubuntu.

Many files and folders are stored in the `home`-directory. One part of this files and folders are your private data, such as in the folders `~/Documents` or `~/Downloads`. Another part of files and folders are configuration-files (most of them are hidden by default and you will not see them in the file-manager unless you enable the option `show hidden files`) and here the problem starts. Possibly some of the configuration-files are valid for both versions of Ubuntu, but not all of them.

You may easily share your private data by creating links to the old data-folders in the `/home`-directory of the new version.

If you just want to install `16.04x64` over `14.04` (overwriting) then you can surely use the old /home-partition. You only need to set the mount-point for the partition and untick the formatting-checkbox during install, so your data are not deleted.

If you want to use both versions you could use a different user-name to install the new version of Ubuntu. If you use different user-names you could share the `/home-partition`, as both versions would have it's own sub-directory in the `/home`-folder, (/home/old_name and /home/new_name).

A problem is that it will be difficult to access the data-folders (like `Documents`, `Downloads`, etc) in `/home/old_name` when you use the new version of Ubuntu with a different user-name, you are not the owner of these files  in this case.

Comment: I'd like to add many of the configuration files begin with a dot '.' which makes them hidden and when using Nautilus you have to select the option to show hidden files to see them.

Comment: I don't agree with you guys. The whole point of having a separate /home partition is to separate the system from the user data. This way, a blown system can be reinstalled without loosing any user data... or upgraded without loosing any user data. The only gotcha, as I mention above, is that some apps config files or databases may get upgraded with 16.04 and then those apps won't run any more in 14.04. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema OP want not only to upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, also want to switch from 32 bit to 64 bit

Comment: So what? The documents/pictures/music/etc folders will all still work with the new system/apps. The only gotcha that I see is what I mentioned. Give me more examples of where you think it could go wrong. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema Why should pictures or videos or text-files be a problem. The problem are the configuration-files. I have the impression that the OP want to use both distros for a while, so both distros should work properly and need their own configurations.

Comment: @mook765 we agree. There will  be some config files, or even databases, once upgraded, won't run again in 14.04. It sounds like the OP is unsure if 16.04 will be entirely successful, and instead of just upgrading 14.04 to 16.04, they want to take a slower/safer? approach... but the same exact problems occur with config files/databases. If somebody was really determined, they could backup and rename the .local/.config/etc folders and let 16.04 rebuild/update existing ones. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema I added a section in the answer for the case the OP just want to make fresh install without keeping older version.

Comment: @mook765 that would be the BEST solution, if the OP just upgraded his original 14.04 system to 16.04 and not try and run "both". Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema It will not be an upgrade like do-release, the OP want to change from x86 to x64 as well, so that means a fresh install anyway.

Comment: @mook765 you're correct. Whether OP want's to overwrite 14.04, or install into another new partition (which is what I think they were asking about). Cheers, Al

Comment: Just to clarify, I am running a small business so I want to be absolutely certain that the 16.04 install is sound and all critical software runs before changing over - and I only have the one machine. I guess I could separate data from /home (in fact most of my data is on a separate disk for this very reason - a couple of years back I migrated us to Ubuntu from anotherwellknownOS) ) but I suspect that the config files could be the problem. So I don't think it will be worth the risk.

Comment: You could use a different user-name for the new install, then you could share the /home-partition, the configuration-files for the new version would not conflict with the old configuration files as the are stored in different folders ( /home/<old_name> and /home/<new_name>). Each versions would have it's own configuration-files, that way both versions would be 100% usable. That was my impression, that you want to use both versions for a while, so you have to keep the configuration-files seperate.

Comment: Why would you expect the configuration files to be a problem? I've been sharing configs across different versions and even different distributions for years. In the vast majority of cases there is no issue. When there is, just delete the conf file and use the default which will be recreated.

Comment: `You can not share a single /home-partition with two different versions of Ubuntu.` - it seems that is simply not true.